# When using Vuetify and importing icons with CDN, is there a way to control the stroke width of the svgs?

Tags: svg, vuejs2, icons, vuetify.js, stroke

I am importing tabler icons in a cdn in my public html folder:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@tabler/icons@latest/iconfont/tabler-icons.min.css">
```

and per the Vuetify docs bringing in the icon library (in plugins/vuetify.js):

```
export default new Vuetify({
    icons: {
        iconfont: "ti",
    }
```

This allows me to use `<v-icon>ti-pencil<v-icon>` (as example) in Vue2 components. All of this works just fine. However, when the icons are inside of the `<v-navigation-drawer>` they are larger and the lines are little too thick. I have only seen the `size` property that works, but it also shrinks the icon, which is not what I want.

Is there a way to change the stroke width on the svgs with css? Or is there another way to affect the thickness of these paths after being imported? Also adjustments to `font-weight` are possible but sadly have no effect on the element.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You need to target the icon with Css selectors and adjust the `font-weight`

Take a look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/blackcrowxyz/pen/yLprRoM?editors=1111).

- If you are dealing with `Svg`s, you can play with `viewBox="0 0 24 24"` values and change their value!(Which is not recommended)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am currently dealing with svg, but helpful nonetheless.

Comment: I have also noticed this happens in newer versions of Vuetify! but check it though :)

Comment: The Vue3, Vuetify4 setup is completely different for icons, so I will have to dig deeper once we switch over to the new framework. :D